# Flutter remove extra space left and right of appbar

Tags: flutter, appbar

So I have been trying to work around this but couldn't I have a search box inside my `appbar` in flutter and I have a `PreferredSize` to help with the height my I have extra space as shown with the blue line in the image below. Can someone help on how to remove this padding-like space as I want the content to align with the content below the search box? Below is the screenshot and my code snippet.

[image]

```
   appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40.0),
          // here the desired height
          child: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: colorGreen,
            title: Container(
              height: 35,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                   ),
                child: Center(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          // Expanded(
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:6),
                              width: 240,
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: TextField(
                                  readOnly: true,

                                  onTap: (){
                        


                                  },
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  controller: controller,
                                  cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                                  onChanged:
                                  onSearchTextChanged,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: "Search",
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        fontSize: 13,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                        fontFamily:
                                        'Montserrat'),
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    prefixIcon: Container(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                                        child:Icon(
                                      Icons.search,
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      size: 15,
                                    )),

                                    suffixIcon: Visibility(
                                        visible: backClear,
                                        child:InkWell(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          },
                                        child: Container(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                                            child:Icon(
                                          Icons.backspace,
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                          size: 12,
                                        )))),
                                   labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                       color: Colors.grey,
                                       fontSize: 14,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                       fontFamily:
                                       'Montserrat'),
                                   // hintText:Center(child: Text(""),), //contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),


                          new Container(
                            width: 2.0,
                            height: 100.0,
                            color: colorGreen,
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: new Theme(
                                    data: Theme.of(context)
                                        .copyWith(
                                      canvasColor:colorGray,
                                    ),
                                    child:Directionality(
                                        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                                      child: ButtonTheme(
                                        alignedDropdown: true,
                                        child: DropdownButton(
                                          //iconSize: 15,
                                          isDense: false,
                                          icon: Container(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                              child:Icon(
                                            //Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                                            Icons.location_on,
                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                            size: 15,
                                          )),

                                          hint: Center(
                                              child: Text(
                                                "All Cities",
                                                textAlign: TextAlign
                                                    .center,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors
                                                        .grey,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                    FontWeight
                                                        .normal,
                                                    fontFamily:
                                                    'Montserrat',
                                                    fontSize: 12),
                                              )),
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors
                                            .grey,
                                            fontWeight:
                                            FontWeight
                                                .normal,
                                            fontFamily:
                                            'Montserrat',
                                            fontSize: 12),
                                          //value: selectedCountry,
                                          onChanged: (newVal) {
                                            setState(() {
                                                 });
                                          },
                                          value: _mySelection,
                                          items:
                                          data.map((item) {
                                            return new DropdownMenuItem(
                                              child: Container(
                                                child: Container(
                                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                                    child: Center(
                                                    child: Text(
                                                  ""
                                                ))),
                                              ),
                                              value: item['id']
                                                  .toString(),
                                            );
                                          }).toList(),

                                          isExpanded: true,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                    ),
                              )
                              ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ))),

          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add titleSpacing 0 and automaticallyImplyLeading false as below:

```
AppBar(
   automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
   titleSpacing: 0
   )
```

Note: It will remove leading icon , you can add your own custom Leading icon.

Answer (score 0):

Make center title to false and add    leadingWidth: 0,

centerTitle: false,

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40.0),
      // here the desired height
      child: AppBar(
        leadingWidth: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: colorGreen,
        title: Container(
          height: 35,
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
               ),
            child: Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 40,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      // Expanded(
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom:6),
                          width: 240,
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: TextField(
                              readOnly: true,

                              onTap: (){
                    


                              },
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              controller: controller,
                              cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                              onChanged:
                              onSearchTextChanged,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: "Search",
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                    fontSize: 13,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    fontFamily:
                                    'Montserrat'),
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                prefixIcon: Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                                    child:Icon(
                                  Icons.search,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  size: 15,
                                )),

                                suffixIcon: Visibility(
                                    visible: backClear,
                                    child:InkWell(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      },
                                    child: Container(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                                        child:Icon(
                                      Icons.backspace,
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      size: 12,
                                    )))),
                               labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                   color: Colors.grey,
                                   fontSize: 14,fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                   fontFamily:
                                   'Montserrat'),
                               // hintText:Center(child: Text(""),), //contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),


                      new Container(
                        width: 2.0,
                        height: 100.0,
                        color: colorGreen,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            child: new Theme(
                                data: Theme.of(context)
                                    .copyWith(
                                  canvasColor:colorGray,
                                ),
                                child:Directionality(
                                    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                                    child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                                  child: ButtonTheme(
                                    alignedDropdown: true,
                                    child: DropdownButton(
                                      //iconSize: 15,
                                      isDense: false,
                                      icon: Container(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                          child:Icon(
                                        //Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                                        Icons.location_on,
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        size: 15,
                                      )),

                                      hint: Center(
                                          child: Text(
                                            "All Cities",
                                            textAlign: TextAlign
                                                .center,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors
                                                    .grey,
                                                fontWeight:
                                                FontWeight
                                                    .normal,
                                                fontFamily:
                                                'Montserrat',
                                                fontSize: 12),
                                          )),
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors
                                        .grey,
                                        fontWeight:
                                        FontWeight
                                            .normal,
                                        fontFamily:
                                        'Montserrat',
                                        fontSize: 12),
                                      //value: selectedCountry,
                                      onChanged: (newVal) {
                                        setState(() {
                                             });
                                      },
                                      value: _mySelection,
                                      items:
                                      data.map((item) {
                                        return new DropdownMenuItem(
                                          child: Container(
                                            child: Container(
                                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                                child: Center(
                                                child: Text(
                                              ""
                                            ))),
                                          ),
                                          value: item['id']
                                              .toString(),
                                        );
                                      }).toList(),

                                      isExpanded: true,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                                ),
                          )
                          ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ))),

      ),
    ),
```

Comment: I did and the space is still there

Comment: Give leadingWidth: 0, inside AppBar

Comment: I added it and still the same

Comment: did you add    titleSpacing: 0,?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the title with flexibleSpace

```
AppBar(
  centerTitle: true,
  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
  flexibleSpace: Container(
    // height: 35, <-- adjust height here
    margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
    width: double.infinity,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    child: Center(
      ....
    )
  ),
)
```